# Something weird is happening when computing surface normal map

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, geometry, computational-geometry

I am using the following code to generate a surface normal map from a depth image:

```
for x in range(depth.shape[0]):
    for y in range(depth.shape[1]):
        try:
            dzdx=(depth[x+1,y,0]-depth[x-1,y,0])/2
            dzdy=(depth[x,y+1,0]-depth[x,y+1,0])/2
        except:
            dzdx=0
            dzdy=0
        sub=np.asarray([-dzdx,-dzdy,1])
        
        normals[x,y,:]=sub/np.linalg.norm(sub)
```

any thoughts as to what is going on?

Comment: What is the dtype of the depth map? is it uint8 or float32? If is uint8 you need to convert to float32 by dividing bby 256 and change the dtype

Comment: @AmitayNachmani it was in uint8 and I converted to float64 by dividing by 256 but then the output was just a red image...

Comment: but what are the values of the depth in your image?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani The range of values or what?

Comment: Yes. what is the renge of depth values?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani In this image (82,254) but they could be between (0,255)

Comment: What is the line of code that use to convert to float32?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani just do --
depth=depth/255.0
-- depth=np.float32(depth)

Comment: Try to  depth=np.float32(depth) and only then depth = depth / 255

Comment: @AmitayNachmani still just getting a red image.

Comment: Do all of  your normals are (0,0,1)?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani no here is a print out of some of them:
array([[ 0.99975857, -0.        ,  0.02197272],
       [ 0.70710678, -0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.70710678, -0.        ,  0.70710678]

Comment: @AmitayNachmani It does seem the y coord i zero typically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in the line:

```
dzdy=(depth[x,y+1,0]-depth[x,y+1,0])/2
```

it should be

```
dzdy=(depth[x,y+1,0]-depth[x,y-1,0])/2
```